# How to insert multiple data using insert_batch in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here i am getting inserted data to database but how to write this in foreach loop to get multiple data please help me as  a fresher am totally confused..

My controller

```
class Student extends CI_Controller {

    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        //call model
        $this->load->model("StudentModel","m");
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("index");
    }
    function savedata()
    {
        //create array for get data from index
    //$data=array(
                     // 'studentname' => $this->input->post('studentname'),
                      //'gender'  =>  $this->input->post('gender'),
                      //'phone'  =>  $this->input->post('phone')
                  // );

        $data = array(
   array(
      'studentname' => 'Reddy' ,
      'gender' => 'Male' ,
      'phone' => '456879'
   ),
   array(
      'studentname' => 'Yalla' ,
      'gender' => 'Female' ,
      'phone' => '12345678'
   )
);


     //mean that insert into database table name tblstudent

        $this->db->insert_batch('tblstudent',$data);

    //mean that when insert already it will go to page index    
        redirect("Student/index");
    }

    function edit($id)
    {
        $row=$this->m->getonerow($id);
        $data['r']=$row;
        $this->load->view('edit',$data);

    }
    function update($id)
    {
        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        $data=array(
                      'studentname' => $this->input->post('studentname'),
                      'gender'  =>  $this->input->post('gender'),
                      'phone'  =>  $this->input->post('phone')
                   );
                     $this->db->where('id',$id);
                     $this->db->update('tblstudent',$data);
                     redirect("Student/index");

    }
    function delete($id)
    {
        $id=$this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('tblstudent');
        redirect("Student/index");
    }

}
```

My model

```
class StudentModel extends CI_Model{

    function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }
    function gettable()
    {
        $query=$this->db->get('tblstudent');
        return $query->result();
    }
    function getonerow($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get('tblstudent');
        return $query->row();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For CodeIgniter 3.x: [insert_batch](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)

For CodeIgniter 2.x: [insert_batch](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#insert)